# 404 error - Finding what wasn't found with wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I am using Wireshark to view my HTTP activity. When there is a 404 Not Found error returned, I can't find an easy way to determine what request could not found. Can anyone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a windows system, try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  I love WS, but Fiddler tends to be more helpful for me in these scenarios.

Comment: +1 If you're debugging HTTP(S) traffic, Fiddler makes it a lot easier. Wireshark is meant for the more general packet analysis, it won't show the data as structured as Fiddler can.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in only traffic to a specific webserver:port combination, wireshark may be useful.  But so many websites have traffic coming from more than one server (bugs, central javascript libraries, ad libraries, server farms, etc) that your Wireshark capture rules will get unwieldy.

I'd recommend using a proxy (such as Fiddler as @Taylor suggested).  If you are using Firefox (or are willing to use it for this debugging) you can also add Live HTTP Headers.